# Swell APIs not returning data on filtering

Tags: javascript, node.js, e-commerce

If anybody has used [swell ecommerce APIs](https://www.swell.is/) before, please help me. I've raised issue on github too but seems like the repo is not actively maintained.

I'm new to swell and decided to try out it for my next project.
I'm using swell APIs to fetch product details on my web app. While some paths are working super fine, I'm having trouble at getting other paths to work for me, especially the query and filtering ones.

Docs are quite unhelpful and not provide enough details.

I'm trying to filter products based on an attribute - `featured_products` which can be either `yes` or `no` or `null` if not set
Based on what you suggest in docs, I've literally tried various combination of paths but nothing works and I always get zero results.

```
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes][featured_products]=yes
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes][featured_products][$eq]=yes
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes][featured_products][$eq]='yes'
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes][featured_products][0][$eq]=yes
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes][featured_products][0]=yes

https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[featured_products][$eq]=yes
https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[featured_products][0][$eq]=yes
```

Otherwise the both of the below given paths work for all products with pagination
[https://api.swell.store/products?limit=25&page=1&where[active]=true](https://api.swell.store/products?limit=25&page=1&where%5Bactive%5D=true)
[https://api.swell.store/products?limit=25&page=1&where[active][$eq]=true](https://api.swell.store/products?limit=25&page=1&where%5Bactive%5D%5B$eq%5D=true)

Please suggest me correct way to use swell APIs for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

after so much effort, finally found the solution via a community thread and this one worked - [https://api.swell.store/products?where[active][$eq]=true&where[attributes.featured_products][$eq]=yes](https://api.swell.store/products?where%5Bactive%5D%5B$eq%5D=true&where%5Battributes.featured_products%5D%5B$eq%5D=yes)